# WHere clause taking much longer time

Tags: mysql

HI i am using this query below its taking hell lot of a time around like 5 mins .. its crazy .. any better way ? or reason fr such long time .. even cutting it into smaller query n getting the value n then finding the common values is much much faster then this.

```
SELECT Product_ItemID
FROM Product_ItemProperties
LEFT JOIN Product_Items USING (Product_ItemID)
WHERE
    Product_CatalogueID = 'xx' AND 
    Field = 'brandname' AND 
    MATCH (Value) AGAINST ('xx' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND 
    Product_ItemID IN (Select Product_ItemID
                       FROM Product_ItemProperties
                       Where Field = 'xx' AND
                             Match (Value) AGAINST ('xx' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
                      );
```

Comment: Try putting EXPLAIN in front of the query to see what indexes are and are not being used

Comment: You need to share more than the query - like the output of the `EXPLAIN`, table schemas, qty of records / relationships, etc.

Answer (score 0):

i dont know why in first where clause you are making  `Field = 'brandname'` and in second inner where clause you are filtering by `Field = 'xx'` . anyway you are double selecting `Product_ItemProperties` while you should use it once.

try this:

```
   SELECT 
Product_ItemID
FROM
Product_ItemProperties
    LEFT JOIN
Product_Items USING (Product_ItemID)
WHERE
Product_CatalogueID = 'xx'
    AND Field = 'brandname'
    AND MATCH (Value) AGAINST ('xx' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
    AND Field = 'xx';
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your itemProperties table has multiple entries for the same "Product_ItemID", and you are looking for something that is both "BrandX", AND has some "OtherProperty" of a different value.  To handle this, you can use that table TWICE (or more if more property values you are interested in... I would suggest having an index on your Product_ItemProperties table by (Product_ItemID, Field, Value) to be best optimization of the query.

For example, you are looking for a Car Brand "X", and secondly, it is a "Blue" car (not considering the catalog component).

Also, notice in this query, I give simplified aliases, and qualify each field with the alias.field so there is no ambiguity which field is coming from where.

The outer WHERE clause is your first criteria, only get those items that have a minimum of the brand name field, and it matches the value you are expecting... From those, join again to the product item properties table, but for the "other" field value you are interested in, and its value.

I was unsure where the cataglog component was, but I suspect that's from the product table and should have ITs alias adjusted.

```
SELECT 
      ByBrand.Product_ItemID,
      P.NameOfProduct, (just an example to get this too)
   FROM
      Product_ItemProperties ByBrand
         JOIN Product_Items P
            ON ByBrand.Product_ItemID = P.Product_ItemID
         JOIN Product_ItemProperties ByOtherField
           ON ByBrand.Product_ItemID = ByOtherField.Product_ItemID
           AND ByOtherField.Field = 'otherPropertyInterestedIn'
           AND MATCH (ByOtherField.Value) against ( 'otherValueLookingFor' IN BOOLEAN MODE )
   WHERE
         ByBrand.Product_CatalogueID = 'someCatalogID'  (or is this from product_items table)
      AND ByBrand.Field = 'brandname'
      AND MATCH (ByBrand.Value) against ( 'brandValueLookingFor' IN BOOLEAN MODE )
```